# In kibana 4 i want to visualise a part of URL field to count

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana-4

I had a field meta.uri. I want to visualize uri. I want a count of `support` and `basic` but not the full uri.
it has

```
/support/user/index?user=some
/support/mine/
/basic/index/
/basic/home?page=1
```

I want only starting part, like:

```
support
basic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kibana4, you can setup a Filter sub aggregation and define each filter.

In the "buckets" section, select "Split lines", then "Filters" for the aggregation type, then define the filter (e.g. myfield:myValue).

If you have logstash, I would suggest making a new field for this value as the events are processed.